# Mock object used insided the to be tested function using spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I can mock a function of a to be tested class in several ways. But how do I mock an object that is created inside of a to be tested method?
I have this to be tested class

```
 @Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7')
 import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
 class totest {
     def get() {
         def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://www.google.com')
         def html = http.get( path : '/search', query : [q:'Groovy'] )
         return html
     }   
 }
```

How do I mock http.get so I can test the get function:

```
class TestTest extends Specification {
     def "dummy test"() {
         given:
             // mock httpbuilder.get to return "hello"
             def to_test = new totest()
         expect:                                                                                               
             to_test.get() == "hello"
     }   
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be to pass the HTTPBuilder into your constructor and then the test code can pass test mocks instead.

But if you want to mock the class construction going on internal to your code, have a look at mocking constructors and classes using GroovySpy and GroovyMock on here: http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html

You would need to do something like the below code:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

class totest {
    def get() {
        def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://www.google.com')
        def html = http.get( path : '/search', query : [q:'Groovy'] )
        return html
    }
}

class TestTest extends Specification{

    def "dummy test"() {

        given:'A mock for HTTP Builder'
        def mockHTTBuilder = Mock(HTTPBuilder)

        and:'Spy on the constructor and return the mock object every time'
        GroovySpy(HTTPBuilder, global: true)
        new HTTPBuilder(_) >> mockHTTBuilder

        and:'Create object under test'
        def to_test = new totest()

        when:'The object is used to get the HTTP result'
        def result = to_test.get()

        then:'The get method is called once on HTTP Builder'
        1 * mockHTTBuilder.get(_) >> { "hello"}

        then:'The object under test returns the expected value'
        result == 'hello'
    }
}
```

Comment: To the OP: Yes, actually, a global Groovy mock is the technical trick that works here, but (1) it only works with Groovy code, not Java, and - most importantly - (2) whenever you need Groovy mocks, especially global ones, or tools like PowerMock for static methods etc., all alarm bells should ring. Bad application design is a reason to refactor for better decoupling (dependency injection instead of classes creating their dependencies by themselves, hidden inside method bodies) and better testability. By no means is it a reason to upgrade your "testing arsenal" so as to avoid refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

What are you testing here? Do you care ***how*** the method gets it's result? Surely you care more that it gets the right result? In that case, the method should be changed so the URL is configurable, then you can stand up a server that returns a known string, and check that string is returned